# What does save mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs

"It was quiet all around, save for the snoring that rose from the lodgings of the servants."
Is it a phrasal verb?

Comment: "save for": except ,other than.

Comment: Not a phrasal verb.

Comment: [save](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/save_3): except. ***save for**: The room was completely dark, save for one candle burning in the corner.*

Comment: Y'all should enter your answers as answers instead of comments.  Then the question would no longer be listed as unanswered, plus you could get credit.

Answer (score 3):

'Save' is like 'except' there, so 'save for' is like 'except for'.  It is being used as a preposition.